# How can I call a python @staticmethod in the class itself (TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable)?

Tags: python-3.x, static-methods

I struggle a little bit to understand how staticmethod behave whithin a class, i creat some code to illustate my purpose :

```
class klass(): 

    @staticmethod 
    def testA(x):
    
        return print(x+1)

    testA(x=1)
```

whene i run this code it says : TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
my question is : how can i call a function in a class whithin this same class ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, indentation in your code is wrong. It should be:

```py
class klass(): 

    @staticmethod 
    def testA(x):
    
        return print(x+1)
```

And regarding your question itself: calling static method requires the class name:

```py
klass.testA(x=1)
```

Comment: I edited the indentation on stackoverflow but it was good when i tried the code..